# Not running Wordcount job in Single node hadoop Cluster After complete setup

Tags: hadoop

> hduser@distributed-desktop:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar
>   hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg
>   /user/hduser/gutenberg-output

After that no output.

I have installed >>

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I configured everything like >> [**Single Node Cluster**](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

When i give jps in cmd it said >>

```
4524 Jps
3609 NameNode
4000 JobTracker
3933 SecondaryNameNode
4433 RunJar
4159 TaskTracker
```

I checked Hadoop drive for file.It says after this cmd

```
hduser@distributed-desktop:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

Found 2 items

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2011-07-31 18:58 /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup          0 2011-07-31 18:51 /user/hduser/gutenberg/pg20417.txt
```

What to do next.

I have been using **Ubuntu 10.10**

Answer (score 4):

Your datanode is not running. This happens quite a lot of time. Go to  /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/ and type ls.
You will get a directory called data. You need to delete all the contents of the folder (do not delete the folder).
Then format your namenode type jps and datanode should be there. That will get all your nodes running.

Comment: The first think to do when something doesn't work is to check the log files and figure it out. Check the datanode log file for any anomaly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. logs are your first saviour. 
Check if the `namespaceID` under `/hadoop.tmp.dir/dfs/name/current` of name node is present in   `/hadoop.tmp.dir/dfs/data/current` of data node.